# Locate a record in a C# CollectionViewSource

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, collectionviewsource

I have a CollectionViewSource that contains a set of indexed records extracted from an MS SQL Server Table called Example using Entity framework 6.2.

Example is declared as a DbSet property of my DbContext class viz:

```
public virtual DbSet<Example> Examples { get; set; }
```

My CollectionViewSource is:

```
CollectionViewSource exampleViewSource;
```

I can move around the collection and count the number of records it contains using the following for example:

```
int selectedRecordPosition = exampleViewSource.View.CurrentPosition;
exampleViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToPrevious();
int numberOfRecordsInCollectionView = exampleViewSource.View.SourceCollection.Cast<Example>().Count();
```

How can I find a particular record in the collection and set it as the record pointer's current location?

I'm looking for something like:

```
    var selectedObject = exampleViewSource.View.SourceCollection.Find(key1, key2);   // example pseudo code.        
    exampleViewSource.View.MoveCurrentTo(selectedObject);
```

key1 & key2 are the Primary access keys for the Example tables' rows.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: What is not working with your code? Are you struggling with the filter query? How does a `Example` item relate to `key1` and `key2`?

Comment: Hi Bionic. As said above "I have a CollectionViewSource that contains a set of indexed records extracted from an MS SQL Server Table called Example using Entity framework 6.2." and "key1 & key2 are the Primary access keys for the Example tables' rows."
Together, key1 and key2 uniquely index each row of the Example table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BionicCode provided a solution my question but someone must have deleted it.
Based on BionicCode's answer I coded ….

```
Example selectedObject = exampleViewSource.View.SourceCollection.Cast<Example>()
                         .Where(selectedRecord =>
                          selectedRecord.Column1Name == key1 && 
                          selectedRecord.Column2Name == key2)
                         .FirstOrDefault();
if (selectedObject == null) break;
exampleViewSource.View.MoveCurrentTo(selectedObject);
```

The only difference is that BionicCode didn't use a Cast and his post disappeared before I could follow it exactly.
Anyway, many thanks BionicCode - you got me off the hook.

Comment: Glad it helped. And thank you for your kind post. I deleted the answer myself as I got the feeling that you didn't recognize it as a solution. I could undelete my answer, but you managed to solve it. You've very good memory.

Comment: As a note: the `FirstOrDefault()` method has an overload which accepts a predicate. So you can shorten the expression by removing/replacing the `Where` method: `exampleViewSource.View.SourceCollection.Cast<Example>()
                         .FirstOrDefault(selectedRecord =>
                          selectedRecord.Column1Name == key1 && 
                          selectedRecord.Column2Name == key2);`

Comment: Thanks BionicCode.  Please feel free to undelete your solution if you wish.